# This script allows append multiple values to a single cell by appending the drop down options in G- sheets.It should be applied to multiple rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

This script allows append multiple values to a single cell by appending the drop down options in G- sheets.It should be applied to multiple rows

```
function onEdit(e) {
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() == 1 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: How should it be applied to multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me it's working correct.  Perhaps you should provide some examples and show us what the problem is.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && sh.getName() == "Sheet0") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1")
    if (!e.value) {
      e.source.toast("opt1")
      e.range.setValue("");
    }
    else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        e.source.toast("opt2")
        e.range.setValue(e.value);
      }
      else {
        e.source.toast("opt3")
        e.range.setValue(e.oldValue + ', ' + e.value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It  works fine instead of one row, I need multiple row to allow multiple value in the row. And it should be applied in one  column only.

Comment: I need a much more detailed explanation of what you want.  Please provide examples

Comment: I want the below code to fetch/reture multiple rows

if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() == 1 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;

Comment: Please do not post code in comments.  I dislike reading code like that